# Pluck value from nested JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I am using ember with ember-data and I need to pluck a value from a nested error response.

If my backend invalidates it could respond with something like this:

```
{"error":{"message":{"invalid input":{"email":["The email has already been taken."]}}}}
```

However, I do not know what the 3rd or 4th nested value cold be so I just need to pluck the 5th value, the error message.

This is what I have:

```
function onSuccess(){
    this.transitionTo('login');
    Notify.success("You are now registered! You can now login.");
};
function failure(reason){
    Notify.alert(reason.responseText.5);
};
...
//Omitted for brevity.
...
//Ember promise returns true or false. 
user.save().then(onSuccess).catch(failure);
```

It would be greate if you could just pluck it out using a number like I have but obviously it does not work like that. Is there a function that ember or jQuery has that allows me to do this?

Comment: Is it always nested `5` deep? Is it always an array containing a string? Are all the nested objects always without siblings?

Comment: Not familiar with ember syntax, but don't you need onSuccess() and failure() in the last line?  (that is, add the parentheses to the function names?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter: no he doesn't. He's passing the functions declared above as arguments.

Comment: @MattBurland Yes it is always nested 5 deep

Comment: You know that the first and second are always `error` and `message` though? Right? In that case you want the first property of the object that is the first property of `message`?

Comment: @MattBurland Exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (or a variation of) could work:

```
var e = {"error":{"message":{"invalid input":{"email":["The email has already been taken."]}}}} ;

function GetDeepest(obj) {
    if (typeof obj === "string") {
        return obj;
    }
    else if (typeof obj === "object") {
        return GetDeepest(obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]);
    }
}

console.log(GetDeepest(e));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aaku72n0/

It will check to see if the object passed in is a string and if it's not it will recurse using the first property of the object. This assumes that there are no siblings (or at least, that you only want to walk down the first siblings in each level), but could be adapted.

This could be simplified even further if you know it's always at the 5th level.

This function doesn't care how deep the string is nested. It'll keep search until it finds it. So these will all give the same result:

```
GetDeepest(e);
GetDeepest(e.error);
GetDeepest(e.error.message);
```

Comment: I like this, thank-you. One quick question, i'm very new to ember so where should I put this if I want to reuse it? There must be a utility or a helper class somewhere

Comment: @nbs189: I'm not familiar with ember, so I couldn't really say. It's just normal Javascript so the same rules apply. But it where ever makes sense. If you are only ever using it in the `failure` handler, you could even nest it inside there.

Answer (score 1):

```
function pluck(object) {
    return object[Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object)[0]];
}

function failure(reason){
    var message = reason.error.message;  //let's skip two levels right away
    var messageText = pluck(pluck(message))[0];
};
```

Comment: `.getOwnPropertyNames` include non-enumerable properties as well as enumerable. Not sure if that's actually desirable versus `.keys`, but is a difference worth noting. I'd also be tempted to make the function `pluck(object, idx)` (with idx = 0 if not supplied) because why not.

Comment: Here's a difference, if you do `pluck([])` it will return `0`, why? Because `getOwnPropertyNames` will return `length` so it's returning the length of the empty array. Replacing `.getOwnPropertyNames` with `.keys` would mean that `pluck([])` return `undefined` instead.